# Find the order of a finite generated abelian group given the presentation

Tags: abstract-algebra

A finitely generated abelian group, $G$, is generated by $|a|=16$ and $|b|=24$, and $a^{2}=b^{3}$. What is the order of $G$? How can a problem like this be solved? Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for this question! I'm studying for a test that has this question as one of the subtopics.

Comment: Do you mean $a^2 = b^2$?

Comment: sorry for the typo.. just corrected it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The gorup $G$ is abelian and so the subgroup $H=\langle b\rangle\leq G$ is normal of ordr $24$ and so: $$G/H\cong\langle a,b\mid a^{16}=b^{24}=1, a^2=b^3, [a,b]=1, b=1 \rangle\cong\langle a\mid a^{16}=1,a^2=1\rangle\cong\mathbb Z_2$$ So under the conditions of $G$ we see that $$|G|=48$$

Comment: Nice work, @Babak! +1

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I fixed a typo in my question. I tried to follow the similar approach but did not work it out..

Comment: @BabakS. Be salamati. Kheili mohtaje doam. Ishalla khosh begzare.